# Adding an offset to one dimension of a tensor, the offset being the entry of another tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am looking for an efficient way to code the sample below with TensorFlow. Below, it is coded in the most silly way with numpy.
The idea is to offset a tensor of size (`batch_size`, `height`, `width`, `channels`) on the height dimension using another tensor value. In other terms:

```
tensor_2[i, j, k, l] = tensor_1[i, j + tensor_offset[i, j, k, l], k, l]
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import numpy as np 
import time

begin = time.time()
b, h, w ,c = 5, 256, 512, 20
offset = np.random.rand(b, h, w , c).astype(int)
image = np.ones((b, h, w ,c))
label = np.ones((b, h, w ,c))
label_offset = np.zeros ((b, h, w,c ))

loss = 0
count = 0

for i in range(b):
    for j in range (h):
        for k in range (w):
            for l in range (c): 
                offset_ = j + np.int(offset [i,j,k,l])
                if offset_ > 255:
                    pass
                else:
                    label_offset[i,j,k,l] = label [i,offset_,k,l]
                    loss =+ label_offset[i,j,k,l]*np.log(image [i,j,k,l])
                    count=+1


loss = loss/count
end = time.time()
print ('duree:', end - begin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [`gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd), with `indices[i, j, k, l]= [i, j+ tensor_offset [i,j,k,l], k, l]` (so `indices` would be of dimension 5).

You can build it like that:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

b, h, w ,c = 2, 11, 13, 7
final_shape = [b, h, w, c]
offset = np.random.randint(low=0, high=h, size=final_shape)
image = np.random.randint(low=0, high=1000, size=final_shape)

input_tensor = tf.constant(image)

m1 = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(b), multiples=[h * w * c]), [h, w, c, b]), perm=[3, 0, 1, 2])
m2 = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(h), multiples=[b * w * c]), [b, w, c, h]), perm=[0, 3, 1, 2]) + offset
not_too_big = tf.less(m2, h)
m2_safe = tf.mod(m2, h)  # Makes sure we don't go too far in the original array
m3 = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(w), multiples=[b * h * c]), [b, h, c, w]), perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])
m4 = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(c), multiples=[b * h * w]), [b, h, w, c])  # No transposition needed here

indices = tf.stack([m1, m2_safe, m3, m4], axis=-1)
tmp = tf.gather_nd(input_tensor, indices)
output = tf.multiply(tmp, tf.cast(not_too_big, tmp.dtype))  # Sets all the values corresponding to j+offset>h to 0
```

EDIT: this works for me with the transposition.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but  it gives the following error: 

Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 4 for 'Tile_4' (op: 'Tile') with input shapes: [5], [4].

I am guessing that is because range (b) and multiples are not of the same shape

Comment: That sounds right, I wasn't using tile correctly. Does it work with the edit ?

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm but I am a bit confused. It takes about 8 secondes with numpy and for loops, 7 seconds with flatenning the matrices and using lists and 10 seconds with your code on tensorflow. I was expecting the code on tensorflow to be much faster.

Comment: Sorry, my gpu was saturated. It takes 3 secondes. Thank you very much you saved my day !

Comment: @louk does it not work correctly ? why did you un-accept my answer ?

Comment: Sorry it seems that my comment was not saved. I was saying that actually there is an issue with the indices. I have made some improvement on your code, I will post the code, let me know your opinion

Comment: If you can change your code I would delete my answer and accept yours

Comment: You're right I've forgotten to transpose and make sure the final indices are where they should be ! I'll work on it and edit

Comment: exactly, that is what I did but I am not sure I have done it right

Comment: I've corrected and tested my code, it does work now. (you cn check for instance that `indices[i, j, k, l]=[i, j+offset[i, j, k, l]%h, k, l]`, and that `output[i, j, k, l]=input[indices[i, j, k, l]]` or `0` depending on the offset, as it should.

Comment: are you doing stereo vision with neural networks, and applying disparity here ? If so, does it work well ? (just curious)

Comment: Thanks again, we have roughly the same code. You're perfectly right, the offset tensor is a disparity map,  I am working on stereo vision with CNN, for the moment I don't have satisfying results but still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

@gdelab
I have made the following improvement to your code:

```
def tensor_offset (input_tensor, offset_tensor, batch, nbcl):

    b, h, w ,c = batch, 256,512,nbcl

    m = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(b), multiples=[w*h*c]), [h,w,c, b])
    m1 = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(h), multiples=[w*b*c]), [b,w,c,h])
    m2 = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(w), multiples=[h*b*c]), [b,h,c,w])
    m2 = m2 +tf.transpose(tf.cast(offset_tensor,tf.int32),perm=[0, 1, 3, 2])
    m3 = tf.reshape(tf.tile(tf.range(c), multiples=[h*b*w]), [b,h,w,c])

    indices = tf.stack([tf.transpose(m,perm=[3,0,1,2]), tf.transpose(m1,perm=[0, 3, 1, 2]), tf.transpose(m2,perm=[0, 1, 3, 2]),m3], axis=-1)
    paddings = tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 0], [0,100], [0,0]])
    output = tf.gather_nd(tf.pad(input_tensor, paddings), indices)

    return output
```

Comment: looks like we ended up on the same solution for the indices. The padding is a good way to handle the too large offsets !